# How to use reduce, map, or filter to create a function to display and count each values of array objects?

Tags: javascript

How can I create a function that will return the number of each breed?

```
const dogs = [
    {
        name:"Cherry",
        breed:["Shiba", "Poodle"]
    },
    {
        name:"Bolt",
        breed:["Shiba"]
    },
    {
        name:"Pumpkin",
        breed:["Chihuahua", "Poodle"]
    },
    {
        name:"Happy",
        breed:["Poodle"]
    },
    {
        name:"Tofu",
        breed:["German Shepherd"]
    }
];
```

I want to print each breeds and its count like below.

```
{
German Shepherd: 1,
Shiba: 2,
Poodle: 3,
Chihuahua:1
}
```

Edit:
Also how can I pass a specific breed as an argument and print only that breed and its count?

I started understanding some concepts and functions but it is still challenging for me to combine multiple different concepts.

Comment: where is them count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real need for `reduce`, `filter`, or `map` here.

1. Create an object to group the scores by breed.
2. [Iterate over the `dogs` array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement), then iterate over the breeds array for each dog. If the breed [doesn't already exist on the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) create it and set the value to zero.
3. Add one to the breed value.

In answer to your comment about passing in a separate breed argument to just get the totals for that breed, just amend the function a little.

```js
const dogs=[{name:"Cherry",breed:["Shiba","Poodle"]},{name:"Bolt",breed:["Shiba"]},{name:"Pumpkin",breed:["Chihuahua","Poodle"]},{name:"Happy",breed:["Poodle"]},{name:"Tofu",breed:["German Shepherd"]}];

// Pass in the dogs array
// and an optional query string
function getBreedCount(dogs, query) {

  // Grouping object
  const obj = {};

  // Iterate over the dogs, and the breeds
  // updating the grouping object as we go
  for (const dog of dogs) {
    for (breed of dog.breed) {
      obj[breed] ??= 0;
      ++obj[breed];
    }
  }

  // If there is a query argument...
  if (query) {

    // ...and the query string is a key on the object
    // Return a string: `<breed>: <value>`...
    if (obj[query]) return `${query}: ${obj[query]}`;

    // ...otherwise return a message that
    // the breed doesn't exist
    return `${query} doesn't exist`;

  }

  // If there is no query argument
  // return the complete object
  return obj;

}

console.log(getBreedCount(dogs));
console.log(getBreedCount(dogs, 'Poodle'));
console.log(getBreedCount(dogs, 'Shiba'));
console.log(getBreedCount(dogs, 'Bobby Davro'));
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: IMO this is exactly what higher order functions are for: to cut the code bloat.

Comment: Two loops is "code bloat"? @punund

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce` and repeat that on the nested arrays:

```js
const dogs = [{name:"Cherry",breed:["Shiba", "Poodle"]},{name:"Bolt",breed:["Shiba"]},{name:"Pumpkin",breed:["Chihuahua", "Poodle"]},{name:"Happy",breed:["Poodle"]}, {name:"Tofu",breed:["German Shepherd"]}];

const result = dogs.reduce((acc, {breed}) => 
    breed.reduce((acc, name) => {
        acc[name] = (acc[name] ?? 0) + 1;
        return acc;
    }, acc)
, {});

console.log(result);
```

Alternatively, you could first flatten the data into an array of strings, and then reduce that:

```js
const dogs = [{name:"Cherry",breed:["Shiba", "Poodle"]},{name:"Bolt",breed:["Shiba"]},{name:"Pumpkin",breed:["Chihuahua", "Poodle"]},{name:"Happy",breed:["Poodle"]}, {name:"Tofu",breed:["German Shepherd"]}];

const result = dogs.flatMap(({breed}) => breed).reduce((acc, name) => {
    acc[name] = (acc[name] ?? 0) + 1;
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick answers! Is it also possible to pass a specific breed as  argument in function and return only that breed and its count?

Comment: Sure, that is possible. Just have a go at it? You can use an `if` statement, or call `filter`... several solutions possible.

Comment: If you want to get a breed and it's count, then it's a matter of accessing the value from the returned object based on the key (which is the breed), like `result.Shiba`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. First, Extract the key you want with `map` (breed).

```js
function getBreed (dog) {
  return dog.breed;
}

console.log(dogs.map(getBreed))
// [Array(2), Array(1), Array(2), Array(1), Array(1)]
```

You can also simplify this with the [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
const breeds = dogs.map(dog => dog.breed)
console.log(breeds)
// The same output
// [Array(2), Array(1), Array(2), Array(1), Array(1)]
```

Then you can merge all arrays into a one-dimensional array with `reduce` and [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```js
const flatten = breeds.reduce((arr, breed) => arr.concat(breed), [])
console.log(flatten)
// ['Shiba', 'Poodle', 'Shiba', 'Chihuahua', 'Poodle', 'Poodle', 'German Shepherd']
```

Finally, You can count items with `reduce`

```js
function count(counter, breed) {
    if (breed in counter)
        counter[breed]++;
    else
        counter[breed] = 1;
    return counter
}
console.log(flatten.reduce(count, {}))
// {Shiba: 2, Poodle: 3, Chihuahua: 1, German Shepherd: 1}
```

If you wondering what happened here you can [see the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) but in short, ‍The counter is an empty object ‍‍`{}` in the first. Then in step 1 it becomes to `{Shiba:1}` because `Sheba` wasn't in the counter. In step 2 it becomes `{Shiba:1,Poodle:1}` for the same reason. In step 3 `Sheba` Increases and counter becomes `{Shiba:2,Poodle:1}` because `Sheba` exists in counter before and etc.

Comment: Thank you! Now I am just trying to pass a specific breed as argument of a function and print only that breed and its count... this is a little difficult for me since I just started learning JavaScript a few month ago.

Comment: @KojiE If you only want to find the count of a specific breed you can simply filter them first and return the `length` of that. `dogs.filter(dog => dog.breed.includes(YOUR_SPECIFIC_BREED)).length`